# std::bind binds "by value", is that true?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just wonder whether the following class will work properly. What I'm a bit scared of is the fact that in the constructor, on the marked line, I bind to values which are just (temporary) arguments. So the question is: Does `std::bind` take the arguments by-value? To me, this is not clear in the documentations I read.

```
class BoundFct {
public:
    BoundFct(function<void(int, int)> fct, int v){
        boundFct = bind(fct, v, _1); // ** PROBLEM HERE ? **
    }

    void call(int i){
        boundFct(i);
    }

private:
    function<void(int)> boundFct;
};
```

As far as I tested, it works as intended. But is it a safe approach that will work properly in any case?

Comment: I think it is stated pretty clearly [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: I do not really understand WHY this question gets downvoted. I think it's a very legitimate question to ask whether something is save or not, considering how often people teach you that this or that approach in your program is dangerous.

Comment: It may seem harsh, but my guess is that it is easy enough to find this out by reading some documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> The arguments to bind are **copied or moved**, and are never passed by reference unless wrapped in `std::ref` or `std::cref`.

There's nothing unsafe about your code. Though it'd be better to take any function in your `BoundFct` constructor, rather than a `std::function<>`.